# Apache URL Rewrite in my API like http://www.example.com/api/list/office?key=abc

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hello currently i have my URL mod as following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/?+]+)$ index.php?a=$1 [nc]
```

This will make the following

www.example.com/api/movie/details/50

head to

```
www.example.com/index.php?a=api/movie/details/50
```

in php i will provide the right code. all good and fine.

but now i want the abillity to do the following in my urls:

```
www.example.com/api/movie/details/50/?key=abcdefgh&country=nl
```

i want this url to be rewritten to something like:

```
www.example.com/index.php?a=api/movie/details/50&key=abcdefgh&country=nl
```

What would the apache rewrite code  be for something like this?

Sorry i am a total noob in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/?+]+)$ index.php?a=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,QSA]
```